# HTML5 videos not playing in ics and above

Tags: android, html, video, jwplayer

I am trying to play html embed videos on android. But it is not playing smoothly in galaxy nexus. audio starts playing on first clicking the play button, but video don't play. Also media player controls are not accessible. some times play button and activity indicator stuck out there..In my webchrome client onShowCustomView method not triggered at all.

Comment: have you enabled hardware acceleration in your manifest - I've needed that to get HTML5 video playing in a webview (see notes on https://gist.github.com/3718414)